# Osgi bundle cannot find osgi service

Tags: apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have 2 osgi bundles (say A and B) running in Jboss Fuse. I am using Felix. 
'A' bundle exposes a service which 'B' bundle uses.  When I deploy both these bundles there is no problem.  When I execute osgi:ls -u, I see that bundle 'B' is using service exposed by bundle 'A'

After I restart these 2 bundles together Bundle 'B' cannot find service exposed by Bundle 'A'. At this stage if I execute command
osgi:ls, I see OSGI service exposed by bundle 'A'.  When I execute osgi:ls -u, I don't see that bundle 'B' is using service exposed by bundle 'A'

I got 2 workaround for this problem

1. At this stage if I restart only bundle 'B', then bundle 'B' finds
   OSGI service exposed by Bundle 'A'. Restarting bundle is not obvious
   official solution :)
2. In bundle 'B', while importing osgi service, if  add cardinality
   as 0:1 then I don't find any issue. But I cant do this as service
   exposed by bundle 'A' is mandatory for some functionality in bundle
   'B'

Can anyone tell me why I am observing this behavior and how I can resolve it ? ?

Comment: Do you use spring:osgi to consume and expose the services ?

Answer (score 0):

Noted that this could happen when bundle B creates its app ctx outside the normal spring extender process. For instance, bundle B creates an app ctx based on an external event and the app ctx imports the osgi service exported from the bundle A. If you are using spring-dm to export/import osgi services, use `ServiceTracker` via `BundleActivator` instead.

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, posting links as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted.